# magento 2.1 admin issue within product categories

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

I have a problem with Magento 2.1 admin, only the products categories page get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

plz help

also, plz if there any recommendation for the most stable magento 2 release